# pd.read_csv() преобразовал некоторые столбцы в [float], хотя в CSV файле были целые значения

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-2.7, dataframe

Есть 2 csv файла, в которых присутствует текстовые и числовые столбцы. Числовые отображаются в виде целых цифр. После конкатенации все числа отображаются с .0 на конце, т.е. в виде десятичных. Как организовать слияние файлов так, чтобы числа оставались целыми? Пример конкатенации ниже:

```
print 'Concatenating with 2-file...'
df1 = "1.csv"
df2 = '2.csv'

files = [pd.read_csv(df1, sep=','), pd.read_csv(df2, sep=',')]
result = pd.concat(files, ignore_index=True)
result.to_csv(df1, index=False)
print 'Done!'
```

Comment: Можете показать вывод следующих комманд: `pd.read_csv('1.csv').dtypes; pd.read_csv('2.csv').dtypes;` ?

Comment: Item Title         object
Brand              object
Category           object
Fixed Price       float64
Description        object
SKU                object
MPN                object
UPC               float64
Main Image URL     object
Quantity          float64
Leadtime          float64
dtype: object

Comment: @MaxU, я так понимаю нужно изменить тип float64 на int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно это случается если у вас хотя бы в одной ячейке значение - `NaN` (Not A Number) или хотя бы одно значение типа `float`.

Пример:

CSV файл:

```
text,a,b,c
aa,1,10,100
bb,,20,200
cc,3,30,300.0
```

читаем:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

результат:

```
In [56]: df
Out[56]:
  text    a   b      c
0   aa  1.0  10  100.0
1   bb  NaN  20  200.0
2   cc  3.0  30  300.0

In [57]: df.dtypes
Out[57]:
text     object
a       float64
b         int64
c       float64
dtype: object
```

как проверить - показать количество NaN's для каждого столбца:

```
In [58]: df.isnull().sum()
Out[58]:
text    0
a       1
b       0
c       0
dtype: int64
```

**Решение:**

Столбцы типов `np.int*` в Numpy/Pandas не могут содержать `NaN` - они будут автоматически преобразованы в `np.float_` если в столбце присутствует хотя бы одно значение `NaN`. Чтобы это исправить надо заменить все значения `NaN` на какое-нибудь целое:

```
In [61]: df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(-1).astype(int)

In [62]: df
Out[62]:
  text  a   b      c
0   aa  1  10  100.0
1   bb -1  20  200.0
2   cc  3  30  300.0
```

Если проблема вызвана `float` значением, то можно округлить значения в столбце и преобразовать к `int`:

```
In [85]: df['c'] = [100, 200, 300.55]

In [86]: df
Out[86]:
  text    a   b       c
0   aa  1.0  10  100.00
1   bb  NaN  20  200.00
2   cc  3.0  30  300.55

In [87]: df['c'] = df['c'].round().astype(int)

In [88]: df
Out[88]:
  text    a   b    c
0   aa  1.0  10  100
1   bb  NaN  20  200
2   cc  3.0  30  301
```

или отбросить дробную часть, преобразовав к `int`:

```
In [89]: df['c'] = [100, 200, 300.55]

In [90]: df['c'] = df['c'].astype(int)

In [91]: df
Out[91]:
  text    a   b    c
0   aa  1.0  10  100
1   bb  NaN  20  200
2   cc  3.0  30  300
```

PS склеивать файлы лучше так:

```
files = ["1.csv", "2.csv"]

(pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files], ignore_index=True)
   .to_csv(output_filename, index=False))
```

Comment: Спасибо! Почему это происходит - доходчиво. А, собственно, как решается данная проблема?

Comment: Это зависит от того чем вызвана проблема - NaN или хотя бы одно значение float... Какой случай у вас?

Comment: в  моём случае проблема в float

Comment: прошу прощения за занудство, но как поступать в случае с NaN?

Comment: @ДмитрийВладимирович, первая часть решения как раз об этом...

Comment: хм, в ответ получаю ошибку: ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '662551172409.0'

Comment: @ДмитрийВладимирович, это у вас строка. Вы можете привести воспроизводимый пример данных? А еще лучше - сделать это в новом вопросе...